# Different method to find fundamental unit

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the quadratic number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{61})$. By Dirichlets unit theorem we know that the unit group has rank $1$. I now want to find a unit of infinite order.

I know that one way to do this is by finding the smallest non-negative integer $y$ for which
$x^2+xy-15y^2=N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(x+y(\frac{1+\sqrt{61}}{2}))=\pm 1$ has an integer solution for $x$. After trying one can show that the smallest one is for $y=5$ and consequently $x=17$. This gives us the fundamental unit $17+5\alpha$, where $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{61}}{2}$.

The problem with this method is that it is a trial and error method and that the first $y$ could be very big. So computational wise this method can be very inefficient.

So I wondered if there is another method for finding the fundamental unit for quadratic fields or if there is an easier way to find at least one unit of infinite order? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Study the theory of Pell-equations. They are closely related and continued fractions allow an efficient calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual method is factoring elements of small norm. In your case,
the ideals generated by $\alpha = 8 + \sqrt{61}$ and $\beta = (7 - \sqrt{61})/2$ have norm $3$, and the quotient is a nontrivial unit, namely $\frac{39 - 5 \sqrt{61}}2$.

Afterwards you have to show that $\frac{39 + 5 \sqrt{61}}2$ is not a power, which is not hard since the fundamental unit is $\ge \frac{1 + \sqrt{61}}2$, and this bounds possible exponents.